# Composer Override a package file

Tags: php, composer-php

I am trying to override a package file, as it doesn't work without modification and it hasn't been updated to fix this.

Package is [`webklex\laravel-pdfmerger`](https://github.com/Webklex/laravel-pdfmerger) and the file is [`PDFMerger.php`](https://github.com/Webklex/laravel-pdfmerger/blob/459f8a6744d1a723362ffeaf73c7dee7075f27c1/src/PDFMerger/PDFMerger.php#L15)

In it has:

```
use fpdi\FPDI;
```

for it to work correctly it needs to be:

```
use FPDI;
```

Obviously whenever I update using composer, this file is of course then incorrect, and at this stage I have to manually go in and change the file to get it working.
There must be a better way?

I've attempted making a copy of the git package, and then using composer to import it and attempt to override, composer snippet is below, but it doesn't do what I want it to do.

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"repositories": {
    "laravel-pdfmerger": {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "****/laravel-pdfmerger-mirror",
            "version": "1.1.1",
            "source": {
              "url": "https://bitbucket.org/****/laravel-pdfmerger-mirror.git",
              "type": "git",
              "reference": "origin/master"
            }
        }
    }
},
"require": {
  ...
  "****/laravel-pdfmerger-mirror": "1.1.1",
  "webklex/laravel-pdfmerger": "1.1"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "VendorExtensions\\xerolaravel\\": "packages/vendorExtensions/xerolaravel",
        "Webklex\\PDFMerger\\PDFMerger\\": "vendor/****/laravel-pdfmerger-mirror/src/PDFMerger"
    }
},
```

Any help here would be great.

--- EDIT ---

updated my composer.json file to remove the repository and change the psr-4 autoload to the following:

```
psr-4": {
    "App\\": "app/",
    "VendorExtensions\\xerolaravel\\": "packages/vendorExtensions/xerolaravel",
    "Webklex\\laravel-pdfmerger\\PDFMerger\\": "vendor/webklex/laravel-pdfmerger/src/PDFMerger"
}
```

But it is still not overriding the original file whenever I do use PDFMerger. Is it because I'm using a Facade?

Comment: Do you really need your solution to be composer-hacking based? e.g. if I give you a pure php solution, would it fit you?

Comment: Sure it might, was just because composer was pulling in the package, but if there is another way, open to it

Comment: For the record: https://github.com/Webklex/laravel-pdfmerger/pull/4 broke the lib, and was released in the version 1.1.0. The issuer of the pull request did a rollback, but this was never merged in the end and is still an open PR https://github.com/Webklex/laravel-pdfmerger/pull/5

Comment: Yer I saw that, a little annoying

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by putting your edited package in a `vendor-custom` directory and adding it to the `autoload` section of your `composer.json`.

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Vendor\\Package": "vendor-custom/vendor/package"
    }
},
```

Gregwar psr-0 example:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "psr-0": {
        "Gregwar\\Cache": "vendor-custom/gregwar/cache",
        "Gregwar\\Image": "vendor-custom/gregwar/image",
        "Gregwar\\ImageBundle": "vendor-custom/gregwar/image-bundle"
    }
},
```

Comment: That's what I've done in the code example, doesnt work "Webklex\\PDFMerger\\PDFMerger\\": "vendor/****/laravel-pdfmerger-mirror/src/PDFMerger"

Comment: In your code example you use the vendor directory used by composer. If you use a different directory, composer will not overwrite it.

Comment: But I want to over-ride it. Are you saying i should put my overridden file, in another folder, in my project, rather than importing my override via composer as well?

Comment: That's how I did it yes.

Comment: Updated my question with my edit as you've suggested, but no luck

Comment: It's possible that you have to create a "psr-0" section and put it in there. I had to do the same thing with a couple of gregwar packages. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Figured this one out at last...

1) Import Forked respository in your composer.json file, but ensure the name matches the name of the package you are replacing; in my case *webklex/laravel-pdfmerger*, like so:

```
"repositories": {
    "webklex/laravel-pdfmerger": {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "webklex/laravel-pdfmerger",
            "version": "1.1.1",
            "source": {
              "url": "url to git",
              "type": "git",
              "reference": "origin/master"
            }
        }
    }
},
```

*Note: Ensure you set a version higher than what is currently available on the original package, so here I added .1 to differentiate the change and tag the commit as this so I can select it.*

2) *require* the package, but ensure you request the version you tagged in your commit:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "webklex/laravel-pdfmerger": "1.1.1"
},
```

3) Update the *autoload* to point to where the package has been imported:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
     ],
     "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Webklex\\PDFMerger\\": "vendor/webklex/laravel-pdfmerger/src"
    }
},
```

Run *composer update* and then dump the autoload.

You should then be able to reference the package in your application as per the instructions in the original package.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, you can actually alias a class to another, and that behaviour include namespaces.

This is extremely useful in legacy projects where you want to start using namespaces but don't want to refactor all usage of the said class.

You have the opposite here, the class is defined in a namespace but the class you are using is not in a namespace, still, aliasing the class would do.

So the function you might be looking for is [`class_alias`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-alias.php).

Here is an example

```
<?php

class FPDI {
  public function __construct() { 
    var_dump('I am FPDI');
  }
}

class_alias('FPDI', 'fpdi\FPDI');

$noNamespace = new FPDI; // would, off course work
$namespace = new fpdi\FPDI(); // would work too, thanks to the class alias
```

So if you are using Laravel, your job should be as simple as aliasing the class correctly.

This can actually be done where you define your [`providers` and `aliases`](https://github.com/Webklex/laravel-pdfmerger#setup).

So at the beginning of `config/app.php`

```
<?php
class_alias('FPDI', 'fpdi\FPDI');

return [

    // all of the below array stays as you have it, it was just snipped for concision purpose 
];
```

Comment: Not sure this would work, as I only need to **use** FPDI, not change the entire class, basically the namespacing the package is using is wrong.

Comment: @SeánMcCabe yes, I saw that, the package was changed from one unofficial one to the official one and that cause the wrong namespacing. Your are not at all changing the entire class here, as you are saying, you just say: *well my class is `FPDI` in no namespace, I want it to also be aliased as if it was defined in the `fpdi\ ` namespace that's it. Exactly as `use Some\Namespaced\Class as MyClass` would allow you to use `MyClass` but would not change the original class namespace.